# Hidden input field not being updated properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the referrer and update the referrer so that my users can go back to the page they came back from. I have a hidden input field which holds the value of the redirect. I have a static value in there just in case the referrer is empty. If the referrer is not empty, I want to update the value of it. Here is the code I have written, I even tested it and it said it was updated, however, I am not being redirected properly, so it is not working.

JavaScript and HTML I have written (keep in mind, I have correctly linked the file and such):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  if (document.referrer != "") {
     document.getElementsByName("redirect").value = document.referrer;
     var test = "false";
     if (document.getElementsByName("redirect").value == document.referrer){
         test = "true";
     }
     alert(test);
     }
  });

<script src="js/referrer.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://www.google.com" />
```

I feel like this is a minor error or there might be some sort of standard I am not following.

Thanks for the help! I appreciate any insight!

Comment: Why are you wrapping your javascript code in Jquery?

Comment: Because the code references an element that only exists after the page has loaded.

Comment: Is it permitted to put JavaScript in JQuery? I feel like that is all legitimate code and I do not receive any errors from the console in Chrome.

Comment: It's completely fine. It just looks weird to have all this plain javascript wrapped in a jquery element. Seemed uneccesary at first, but perhaps @Diodeus is correct about the reason.

Comment: JQuery is your friend, if you are going to adopt it in one place, you should adopt it anywhere you can. It will make your life much easier (and much more readable for others after you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing document.getElementsByName will return an object array that DOES NOT include the value. There is no way to change the value (That I know of and have tried) when using the getElementsByName. I have solved this issue by using getElementById, it actually works properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what the problem is off hand by what you've given me. But what I can say is that if you are going to use JQuery in one place (document ready function) then you should also use it to grab the value of your input field.

It would also help if you put an Id on the input field instead of doing it by name. Ids are the best way to get a specific element. That could be your problem too.

Then call it using:

```
$("#ID").val()
```

so your code would become:

```
if($("#ID").val() === document.referrer)
```

I would also suggest using triple equals as well. But that is completely up to you.

I've never done anything with document.referrer, but there might be a better way of doing that as well.

Answer (score 0):

One odd thing is that you are setting these 2 things equal to each other

```
 document.getElementsByName("redirect").value = document.referrer;
```

and then immediately testing if they're equal to each other.

```
 if (document.getElementsByName("redirect").value == document.referrer)
```

I can't say that this is your issue, but it's bad coding and should be fixed.

Comment: That's because I was debugging it and checking to see if it actually worked. I originally had it with just one line, but I have added on since to try to see what's going on.

Comment: Ah. Maybe try `console.log(document.getElementsByName("redirect").value)` instead. Or if you don't like the console `alert(document.getElementsByName("redirect").value)`

Answer (score 0):

I think a single letter is tripping you up here.

```
if (document.getElement**s**ByName("redirect").value == document.referrer){
```

There's no singular equivalent for 'byName', so you do end up with an array (or at least, an array-like object). Unlike IDs, it is allowable for multiple inputs to have the same name. The easiest solution is this:

```
if (document.getElementsByName("redirect")[0].value == document.referrer){
```